# How to set the cell format (as date and time difference formate)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am new to google app scripts.I have created a google sheets from my FR which parses data first based on condition and then based on type of value. I was able to do this successfully using script but from this newly created google sheets the column B is a time Delta value and column C is cumulative sum of Column B.
The cloumn B and column C format is time Delta format not time in AM or PM. can anyone help me in this issue. i am able to set date format in a cell not able to do the same in whole colum
I am attaching a screen shot of the google sheet.

Here's my code

```
function format() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet4').getRange('A1:A5');
cell.setNumberFormat('dd-mm-yyyy');
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to convert the column A dates from `dd/MM/yyyy` to `dd-MM-yyyy`

You can do it with the [new Date()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) format:

```
    function format() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet4');
      var dates = sheet.getRange('A1:A5').getValues();

      for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++){

           sheet.getRange('A'+(i+1)).setValue(new Date(new Date(dates[i]))).setNumberFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
      }
     }
```

You have to loop through each row and apply setNumberFormat to the formatted value as Date.

Comment: the code above still applies only to cell A1:A5 unable to do till last row with non zero value

Comment: Change `'A1:A5'` to `'A1:Ayour last row'`, or create a new variable `lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()` and then `'A1:A'+lastRow`